# call plugin in joomla component

Tags: plugins, joomla, components

How can i call joomla 'Simple Picture Slideshow' plugin in any joomla component. Have any solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call any event of plugin which is defined in that plugin.

```
$dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
$data = array($argu1, $argu2);   // any number of arguments you want
return $dispatcher->trigger($eventName, $data);
```

Answer (score 7):

Best way to call content plugins in Joomla! 1.5 and above is just use:

```
$text = JHTML::_('content.prepare', $text);
```

http://docs.joomla.org/Triggering_content_plugins_in_your_extension

Answer (score 2):

In Joomla, plugins are not called in the typical sense, they are triggered by various events. The plugin listens for the particular event that triggers it. In this case, you would need to look and see what even Simple Picture Slideshow listens for, then add that trigger to your component. The only way to guarantee that a plugin will be triggered all the time is have it listen for one of the global system events, these happen regardless of the code in the component, they happen at the framework level. If a plugin is triggered by a non-global event, then you would need to either change the plugin or add the event to every component you want using the plugin.

Global system event reference - http://docs.joomla.org/Reference:System_Events_for_Plugin_System

Plugin reference - http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin

Answer (score 2):

This question is specifically for `Content` plugin of joomla.

You can trigger any plugin event in your component.

Here is an example to trigger `content` plugin `onPrepareContent` event.

```
$content = new stdClass;
$content->text = 'Your content body with proper tag or 
                    content wich you want to replace. 
                    For example:  {loadmodule mod_login}';
$atricle = array();

JPluginHelper::importPlugin('content');
$dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();

JDispatcher::getInstance()->trigger(
    'onPrepareContent',
    array(
        &$content,
        &$atricle,
        null
    )
);
```

Or if you want to trigger only specific plugin for your component, then you can use,

```
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('content', 'loadmodule');
```

Second argument is name of the plugin which you want to use.

Similarly, you can call user plugin event in your component.

```
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('user', 'contactcreator');

JDispatcher::getInstance()->trigger(
    'onUserAfterSave', 
    array(
        $user, 
        $isnew, 
        $success, 
        $msg
    )
);
```

Comment: You may also read Joomla! doc for to how to support plugin in your component. https://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_plugins_in_your_component

Comment: Thanks! calling the plugin event is great, and we can also create our own events.